# Issue with a parallax based on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Editing this question for clarity.

I am trying to create a parallax effect based on the `mousemove` but I am having a few problems.

1) I cannot get the correct `window` offset. If you see the JSFiddle you will notice that offset is related to the position where the pointer enter the `window`. I want to have the `asset-layer` offset always based on the middle of the `window`. What can I do to solve this?

2) You will notice that the parallax changes the intensity as I duplicate it. I previously tried a loop to iterate between all them but I did not succeed. Why is this happening and how can I prevent?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/didacus/e2r55tcw/1/)

HTML

```
<section class="one">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="two">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="three">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConstant = .015;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (currentX == '')
       currentX = e.pageX;

    var xdiff = e.pageX - currentX;
    currentX = e.pageX;

    if (currentY == '')
        currentY = e.pageY;

    var ydiff = e.pageY - currentY;
    currentY = e.pageY;

    $('.parallax div').each( function(i) {
      var $el = $(this);
      var movementx = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
      var movementy = (i + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
      var newX = $el.position().left + movementx;
      var newY = $el.position().top  + movementy;

      $el.css({left: newX + 'px', top: newY + 'px'});
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.one { background-color: pink; }
.two { background-color: lightgray; }
.three { background-color: orange; }

.parallax {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.asset {
    position: absolute;
}
.asset-layer1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.asset-layer2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.asset-layer3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.asset-layer4 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `each` inside a loop is the same as a loop inside a loop!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Where is the relevant HTML?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of `.parallax-...` elements? Could there be more having the same class (How many `parallax-1` there is for example?)?

Comment: How about you make all our lives easier and make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Chris, I will do.

Comment: You've already done it yourself by this `$('.parallax-' + z)`. So what's your actual problem? The actual selectors generated should be `".parallax-0"`, `".parallax-1"`, ...

Comment: @Hopeless It did not work though. I have now edit the post for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but your issue is probably that

```
var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
```

Should be

```
var movement = (z + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
```

And actually the inner `each` is irrelevant so you could write:

```
for (var z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
  console.log(z);
  var $el = $('.parallax-' + z);
  var movement = (z + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
  var movementy = (z + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
  var newX = $el.position().left + movement;
  var newY = $el.position().top + movementy;

  $el.css('left', newX + 'px');
  $el.css('top', newY + 'px');
}
```

But rather than applying a separate class to each item use a single class for all similar items and then do something like:

```
for (var z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
  console.log(z);
  var $el = $('.parallax').eq(z);
```

Or,imo, even better:

```
$('.parallax').each( function(i) {
      var $el = $(this);
      var movementx = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
      var movementy = (i + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
      var newX = $el.position().left + movementx;
      var newY = $el.position().top  + movementy;

      $el.css({left: newX + 'px', top: newY + 'px'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really complicating the problem. It should be a simple logic like this. The input here is just the distance from the mouse pointer to the center point of the window. The calculation is just done with that input. Don't need to calculate any mouse movement difference. Also more exactly we need the coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the center point (so it can have negative values, in which case it should be on the left of the center point).

Based on that simple logic, the code can be much more simplified and looks like this:

```
var movementConstant = .05;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   var xToCenter = e.pageX - window.innerWidth/2;
   var yToCenter = e.pageY - window.innerHeight/2;

   $('.parallax div').each( function(i) {
     var $el = $(this);
     var newX  = (i + 1) * (xToCenter * movementConstant);
     var newY = (i + 1) * (yToCenter * movementConstant);      
     $el.css({left: newX + 'px', top: newY + 'px'});
   });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e2r55tcw/2/)

I hope I understand about what you want correctly.

Comment: this is great. It solves the first problem I was having. Thank you for that. Now there is still the intensity problem 2). Why is the parallax intensity increasing as I duplicate it?

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not understand what you mean by ***parallax intensity*** as well as by ***duplicate it***?

Comment: sorry about that. Let me try to explain better. Notice on your 'Demo' that the parallax layers in `<section class="two">` and `<section class="three">` move further than on `<section class="one">`. As I continue to add more `<section>` the offset on the parallax layers increase.